# Sitecore Workflow Items Stay in the Approved State

Tags: workflow, sitecore, sitecore6

My problem is items that complete the workflow and get auto published still show a State of 'Approved'.  Right now my users cannot edit items that are in this final state.  Is there a way to make Sitecore clear the State field after auto publish or do I need to give every user permission for the 'Approved' workflow state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give permission to the "Approved" workflow state.

Comment: This will work. To be specific. If i am not wrong, giving "Content Editor" the permission to Approved state will do the work. As, when a content editor try's to edit the item, he or she should have the permission to rewrite the Approved state to Draft state.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the specifics of your workflow configuration, I am going to guess that the users need to click "Edit" to unlock the item and reset its workflow state. This button can be found on the Home and Review tabs in the content editor.